# My selenium driver stops working after I pass the login page (javascript)

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I have a basic automation test where I am logging into a hotel booking website using selenium and cucumber, then after I login I click a checkbox called a wifi checkbox. I can enter the username and password just fine on the login page but after I login selenium stops working. I cant click on the wifi button. I tried implicit wait but that does not work.

Here is my code

```
const {By, Key, Builder} = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("chromedriver");

const {Before,Given,When,And,Then}=require('@cucumber/cucumber')

let driver =  new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

var {setDefaultTimeout} = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);



  Given('when you are on the login page', async function () {
   
    await driver.get("https://automationintesting.online/#/admin")



  });



  When('you enter login credentails' ,  function () {

     
     driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");

     driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");

     driver.findElement(By.id("doLogin")).click();


  });

  When('your logged in ',{ implicit: 3000 },async ()=> {

    
    driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: 3000 });
  await driver.findElement(By.id("wifiCheckbox")).click();

    

  });







  Then('you should be on the profile page', function () {

    driver.getCurrentUrl()


  });
```

this code below works just fine

```
     driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");

     driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");

     driver.findElement(By.id("doLogin")).click();
```

Its this code below that does not work

```
 driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: 3000 });
  await driver.findElement(By.id("wifiCheckbox")).click();
```

**I AM GETTING REQUEST FAILED 403 ERROR**

Comment: you might try a standard sleep after logging in.  If the site doesn't redirect you after login, Selenium won't wait... but you still may need to wait a small amount of time for the session cookie to be set.

Comment: Are you running in headed (non-headless) mode so you can see the behavior in the browser? Do you get a 403 error message in the console log?

Answer (score 0):

The Request Failed `403` error is typically an HTTP status code indicating that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

```
const { By, Key, Builder } = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("chromedriver");

const { Before, Given, When, And, Then } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');

let driver = new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
const { setDefaultTimeout } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');
setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);

Given('when you are on the login page', async function () {
  await driver.get("https://automationintesting.online/#/admin");
});

When('you enter login credentials', async function () {
  await driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
  await driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");
  await driver.findElement(By.id("doLogin")).click();
});

When('you are logged in', async function () {
  const wifiCheckbox = await driver.findElement(By.id("wifiCheckbox"));
  await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(wifiCheckbox), 10000, 'Wi-Fi checkbox not found');
  await wifiCheckbox.click();
});

Then('you should be on the profile page', async function () {
  const currentUrl = await driver.getCurrentUrl();
  // Further validations or assertions can be added here
});
```

Ensure you have imported the necessary packages

Answer (score 0):

Java runs actions synchronously, like taking steps in order. It waits for each step to finish before moving on. On the other hand, JavaScript is inherently asynchronous, like handling tasks in parallel, making it better for dynamic websites.

So, since `sendKeys`, `click`, `setTimeouts` and `getCurrentUrl` methods returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
you should add the `async` `await` keywords to it.
In addition you should add "wait" before accessing elements especially after page navigation, but in this case "wait" alone would not solve this problem because there is an element that being loaded slowly (#room1)
and causes that `wifi checkbox` to move a bit and makes Selenium "lose" it.
so by combining both the `implicit wait` and `explicit wait` it will work:

```js
const { By, Key, Builder } = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("chromedriver");

const { Before, Given, When, And, Then } = require("@cucumber/cucumber");

let driver = new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

var { setDefaultTimeout } = require("@cucumber/cucumber");
setDefaultTimeout(60 * 1000);

Given("when you are on the login page", async function () {
  await driver.get("https://automationintesting.online/#/admin");
});

When("you enter login credentails", async function () {
  await driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");

  await driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password");

  await driver.findElement(By.id("doLogin")).click();
});

When("your logged in", async () => {
  await driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: 3000 });

  const wifiCheckbox = await driver.wait(
    until.elementIsVisible(
      await driver.findElement(By.id("wifiCheckbox")),
      10000,
      "Wi-Fi checkbox not found"
    )
  );
  await wifiCheckbox.click();
});

Then("you should be on the profile page", async function () {
  await driver.getCurrentUrl();
});
```

These adjustments may be required due to the async nature of JavaScript, which can make it more responsive and faster for web interactions.

Please note that you have a typo in the word "credentails" and a redundant "space" in the end of "your logged in " step name.
those can cause problems so I've fixed those for you, just make sure to much those lines in your *feature* file.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the implicit timeout before you find the elements.

Like this:

```
When('you are logged in', async function () {
  await driver.manage().setTimeouts({ implicit: 10000 });

  await driver.findElement(By.id("wifiCheckbox")).click();
```